# search for a cell from one excel and search in another excel and print if its not there using perl

Tags: excel, perl

I'm new to perl. I have two excel files containing huge no of rows and just two columns. I want to get each cell from one of the excel files and search whether its there in another excel file or not. if its not then print that cell.
I believe that if I get each cell from one of the excel and search it in another and then run a for loop for all the rows it will be done.
I reached upto getting the cell from first excel but how to search whether it is there in the another excel and printing it is the issue.

can anybody help. ??

Comment: How do you get the first cell?

Comment: I used use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel; and then my $cell1 = $Sheet1 -> {Cells}[$row1][$col1];

Comment: I haven't worked with excel files in perl before. How did you get `$Sheet1`? Edit your post and add some code.

Comment: @Einstein You have yet to respond on your other forum post from a week ago: [`compare excel sheets`](http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/955928-compare-excel-sheets).  Unless you respond, you're just wasting people's time.  Also, please read [`how to ask a good question`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but this might give you some ideas. It's completely untested, though.

```
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();

my $workbook1 = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');
if (!defined $workbook1) { die $parser->error(), ".\n"; }

my $workbook2 = $parser->parse('Book2.xls');
if (!defined $workbook2) { die $parser->error(), ".\n"; }

$worksheet1 = $workbook1->worksheet('Sheet1');
$worksheet2 = $workbook2->worksheet('Sheet1');

my ($row_min1, $row_max1) = $worksheet1->row_range();
my ($col_min1, $col_max1) = $worksheet1->col_range();

for my $row1 ($row_min1 .. $row_max1) {
  for my $col1 ($col_min1 .. $col_max1) {

    my $cell1 = $worksheet1->get_cell($row1, $col1);

    my ($row_min2, $row_max2) = $worksheet2->row_range();
    my ($col_min2, $col_max2) = $worksheet2->col_range();
    my $found_match = 0;

    for my $row2 ($row_min2 .. $row_max2) {
      for my $col2 ($col_min2 .. $col_max2) {

        my $cell2 = $worksheet2->get_cell($row2, $col2);
        if ($cell1->value() eq $cell2->value()) {  # or == ?
          $found_match = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      break if $found_match;
    }

    if (!$found_match) {
      print $cell1->value, "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

This is mostly from here: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm

Comment: I tried this but this is not printing just one cell its printing literaally all the cellls where it was not equal. means if its matching for one value it'll skip that row and for all rest it 'll print that celll value.

Comment: @Einstein I fixed a bug in the code above. BTW, are the cell values strings or numbers?

Comment: Found match was a great help appreciate the answer. I was able to carry over from there.

Comment: if the cell value is a blank how to avoid or rather skip that cell.